multiple securityFilterChains
I'm upgrading to spring security 6 java configs from spring 5 xml based.
The application requires form login and a rest service endpoint authentication. The rest authentication was implemented using the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.
I first got the UI form login working, then added the Rest service endpoint filter chain..
I ordered the beans as described in the documentations.. My service api is 1 and the UI is 2..
Now when I try to git the UI it only goes through the service api filter chain.. I can't figure out why since the url is not in that filter chain..
Hopefully this is something pretty basic, but Im not making progress.. Any help is appreciated..
Here is the code for the filter chains.. When both are active I cannot even hit http://localhost:8080/app/login
    @Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    RestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter restServicesFilter = restServicesFilter(authenticationManager);

    http
       .securityMatcher("/services/**")
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/services/**").hasAnyRole("USERS")

        )
        .addFilterBefore(restServicesFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> 
            exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(restServicesEntryPoint())
        );

    return http.build();
}


     @Bean
 @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain uiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // Disable CSRF for simplicity, as in your XML config
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            
            // Frame options configuration (SAMEORIGIN policy)
            .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
            
            // Static resources and API endpoints with no security
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/services/suggest/**","/soap/**","/services/search/add","/services/search/commit","/services/admin/register","/services/admin/unregister","/services/admin/addjob","/services/jms/process","/services/search/update","/services/download/cloud","/services/jms/test","/services/jms/requeue/**","/health/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/css/**","/assets/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/gui/*.jsp").hasRole("USERS")
                .requestMatchers("/gui/**").hasAnyRole("USERS")
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
               // .anyRequest().authenticated()  // All other requests require authentication
            )
            
            // Form login configuration
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("pw")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
            )
            
            // Logout configuration
            .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            )
            .exceptionHandling(handling -> handling.accessDeniedPage("/403"));
        
        return http.build();
    }

Here is the log when trying to hit the url http://localhost:8080/app/services/search/test?j_username=dan&j_password=dan. The logs looks to know about the requestMatcher "/services/**" but will not work when i have 2 securityChains in play.. In this example I can login with http://localhost:8080/app/gui/findPatients.jsp(get redirected to login and login works). This hits the security chain Order(2).. but the service api still fails(the api security chain will work if it's the only security chain)
http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/services/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@47344873, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@62256cc6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@7273d63e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@74b293bc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6619ac5, com.wiredinformatics.listener.RestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@143c4644, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6e9740eb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6666fd9e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5fb4cf36, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@13778e0a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3a8ada19]] (1/2)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3a266363, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@732c6bbd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@6c1618db, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e3ed74, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@53398bc6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c5dbf7f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5e7b33df, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@11a35d36, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5d41dfa, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@450152d4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5f1a12e5]] (2/2)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal - Securing POST /services/search/test?j_username=invenio&j_password=invenio
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter.requiresLogout - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.requiresAuthentication - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest - matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check - Authorizing POST /services/search/test?j_username=dan&j_password=dan
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check - Checking authorization on POST /services/search/test?j_username=dan&j_password=dan using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@54298856
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession - No HttpSession currently exists
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext.init - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext.init - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.defaultWithAnonymous - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] 10 Oct 2024 13:56:41 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException - Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied


there is a lot of information missing here when I try to git the UI git? im assuming GET, and i dont see any request in your question. We have no idea what it is you are getting. the url is not in that filter chain what URL? we cant see what you see! Also, why have you not enabled DEBUG logs and read them? and you should always include DEBUG logs in your question.

added logs and additional information as to what I'm trying to get working

added  .securityMatcher("/services/**") that i found in another post to the apisecurity chain, but still not working yet

I finally found an answer.. I had to add an AntPatternRequestMatcher to the
http.securityMatcher(new AntPatternRequestMatcher("/services/**"))
